# How to properly set jQuery calendar widget regional setting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

In my application I am taking the locale value and then trying to replace shorter month names to full ones. Below is the code snippet

```
var localeCookie = $.cookie("org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver.LOCALE");
if(localeCookie === null || localeCookie === undefined || localeCookie === "en") {
    localeCookie = "";
}
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ localeCookie ] );
var completeMonthNames = $.datepicker.regional[ localeCookie ].monthNames;
```

How to make the above code work? I have looked up the variable "localeCookie" through firebug and it does take the language parameter like "fr", "de" etc. It works well for "en" default locale, but for other locales even when the debugger says that it has correct values, still the javascript says it cannot find definition. I have tried wrapping localeCookie around string like `$.datepicker.regional[String(localeCookie)]` but it still refuses to work?

What type constraint am I not reading in the jQuery documentation?

Comment: do you get what you expect? `console.log(localeCookie , $.datepicker.regional[ localeCookie ])`

Comment: @epascarello I haven't run your snippet, but short answer is no. $.datepicker.regional[localeCookie] comes undefined even though firebug tells me the key is fine. I am suspecting JQuery isn't liking my variable localeCookie, but do not understand why?

Comment: Did you include the locale js files?

Comment: Wait, there is a locale JS file to be included! Argh! ok I think, I know the problem now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the locale js files that are required for that language.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n